# Get Dask diagnostic values for a Dask distributed client

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Is there any way to get Dask diagnostic data, not the dashboard for a `Dask.distributed client`?

Dask already provides a nice `Bokeh dashboard`, where it plots quite a lot diagnostics informations. However, what I want are not the plots but their values. Something like, along with the timestamp, progress value, cpu and memory usage. I would like to store these values in a database for my own monitoring purposes.

So far, I have tried to use function `Dask.distributed.get_task_stream()`, it provides information about the workers in a list but I would like to get in a stream manner, what exactly **Task Stream** plot shows in the dashboard.

Note: there exists a package called `dask.diagnostics` and from there you can import a `ProgressBar`, `Profiler()`, `ResourceProfiler()` etc., However, from my current understanding, they are only for a `single machine scheduler` and not for a `distributed scheduler`. Am I right? Or, can I use them for a distributed environment?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases we recommend the `get_task_stream` function that you've already found.

If you want to trigger something on every transition you might consider the Scheduler plugins.  In particular, the task stream plugin that feeds that dashboard lives here:

https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/diagnostics/task_stream.py